# Tumblr "Sign In" button not working in Android webview

Tags: android, oauth, webview, tumblr

Recently I've developed an application able to post to Tumblr, for the aouth flow implementation I've used my own webview, when I get the response to the token request I open a new activity with an embedded webview in order to enter the credentials in the webpage obtained. This is working fine with Twitter, but somehow with Tumblr "Sign In" button does not work ! the only way to get logged in is pressing enter on the virtual keyboard. Do I need to add something to my webview in order to get the "Sign In" button working?

Thank you !

[image: tumblr login page]

My webview activity:

```
public class InAppBrowserActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyViewClient());
    setContentView(webview);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: can you share your code about how to implement Tumblr Login in android using Jumblr api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you forgot to enable JavaScript?

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```